# New PC build does not output on monitor

Tags: display, vga

I've built a new PC and connected the onboard graphics card (which has DVI-E, HDMI and VGA output) via VGA to an old Viewsonic monitor which has only a VGA connector. The monitor displays the message: "no signal". The same monitor was working fine with the old build (also connected to the on-board graphics card).

I've connected a Dell monitor via DVI-E and it works fine, so the PC works ok.

Do you have any suggestions (besides testing new cables)?

Comment: You may have to configure VGA output in the BIOS.

Comment: I can configure only the priorities: IGX (onboard graphics) or PCI-E. I can't select the signal output.